# 467C-CodeForces Time Complexity

Tags: time-complexity

Today, i tried so many times to solve a problem in codeforces, i used dp but still fail TL. Can u guys point out which part in my code take long time? thanks !

```
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>

    typedef long long ll;

    ll n,m,k,a[5000],result=0, memo[5000][5000], sum[5000];

    ll maxsum(int p,int t)
    {
        if (t==0) return 0;
        if (memo[p][t]!=-1)
            return memo[p][t];
        ll tp=0;
        for (int i=p+m; i+(t-1)*m-1<n; ++i)
            tp=std::max(tp,maxsum(i,t-1));
        memo[p][t]=tp+sum[p];
        return memo[p][t];
    }

    int main()
    {
        std::ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
        std::cin.tie(0);
        std::cin>>n>>m>>k;
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
            std::cin>>a[i];
        for (int i=0; i<m; ++i)
            sum[0]+=a[i];
        for (int i=1; i+m-1<n; ++i)
            sum[i]=sum[i-1]+a[i+m-1]-a[i-1];
        std::fill(&memo[0][0],&memo[n][k],-1);
        for (int i=0; i+k*m-1<n; ++i)
            result=std::max(result,maxsum(i,k));
        std::cout<<result;
    }
```

Link of my submission here: http://codeforces.com/contest/467/submission/24322748

Comment: Help me pls @@, this make me headache @@@@@@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer may be zero, thus you should set all elements of your dynamic array to -1 at the beginning, and then in your function you should check if whether they are equal to -1.

Comment: It would be great if you could paste here corrected code. It would clear out all ambiguities.

Comment: I made same mistake before.  [Here are my codes](https://www.diffchecker.com/46o59rl6) . You can use this technique for dp problems.